# Using Loop inside a function with If statement in R

Tags: r, function, loops, if-statement, seurat

I am learning about function in R recently. I successfully make this function work

```
check_spot = function(one_spot, cluster_id, marker_gene){
one_spot = sample(glio_spatial@assays$SCT@misc$vst.out$cells_step1, 1)
cluster_id  = sample(as.data.frame(Idents(glioblastoma))[,1], 1)
marker = FindMarkers(glioblastoma, ident.1 = cluster_id)
marker = cbind(gene = rownames(marker), marker)
rownames(marker) = 1:nrow(marker)
marker_gene = sample(marker[,1], 5)
a = as.data.frame(glio_spatial@assays$Spatial@counts)
b = a[one_spot]
b = rename(b,c("count_spot" = all_of(one_spot)))
b = subset(b, b[,1] != 0, )
b = cbind(gene = rownames(b), b)
rownames(b) = 1:nrow(b)
intersection = inner_join(b, marker)
if (marker_gene[1] %in% intersection[1,]) sprintf("The gene %s is a marker gene for the cluster %s and is expressed in the spot %s", marker_gene, cluster_id, one_spot)
else if
     (marker_gene[2] %in% intersection[1,]) sprintf("The gene %s is a marker gene for the cluster %s and is expressed in the spot %s", marker_gene, cluster_id, one_spot)
else if
     (marker_gene[3] %in% intersection[1,]) sprintf("The gene %s is a marker gene for the cluster %s and is expressed in the spot %s", marker_gene, cluster_id, one_spot)
else if
     (marker_gene[4] %in% intersection[1,]) sprintf("The gene %s is a marker gene for the cluster %s and is expressed in the spot %s", marker_gene, cluster_id, one_spot)
else if
     (marker_gene[5] %in% intersection[1,]) sprintf("The gene %s is a marker gene for the cluster %s and is expressed in the spot %s", marker_gene, cluster_id, one_spot)
else
    sprintf("The gene %s is a marker gene for the cluster %s, but not expressed in the spot %s", marker_gene, cluster_id, one_spot)
 }
```

It will print this:
Joining, by = "gene"

'The gene NKD1 is a marker gene for the cluster 8, but not expressed in the spot CTACCCTAAGGTCATA-1'

'The gene RPL8 is a marker gene for the cluster 8, but not expressed in the spot CTACCCTAAGGTCATA-1'

'The gene TSPAN13 is a marker gene for the cluster 8, but not expressed in the spot CTACCCTAAGGTCATA-1'

'The gene HSBP1 is a marker gene for the cluster 8, but not expressed in the spot CTACCCTAAGGTCATA-1'

'The gene BHLHE41 is a marker gene for the cluster 8, but not expressed in the spot CTACCCTAAGGTCATA-1'.

Then, I have tried to make a simpler function for this function using for statement to get more generalise number of samples, I try this

```
check_spot = function(one_spot, cluster_id, marker_gene){
one_spot = sample(glio_spatial@assays$SCT@misc$vst.out$cells_step1, 1)
cluster_id  = sample(as.data.frame(Idents(glioblastoma))[,1], 1)
marker = FindMarkers(glioblastoma, ident.1 = cluster_id)
marker = cbind(gene = rownames(marker), marker)
rownames(marker) = 1:nrow(marker)
marker_gene = sample(marker[,1], length(marker[,1]))
a = as.data.frame(glio_spatial@assays$Spatial@counts)
b = a[one_spot]
b = rename(b,c("count_spot" = all_of(one_spot)))
b = subset(b, b[,1] != 0, )
b = cbind(gene = rownames(b), b)
rownames(b) = 1:nrow(b)
intersection = inner_join(b, marker)
for (i in 1:length(marker_gene)){
    if (marker_gene[i] %in% intersection[1,]) {sprintf("The gene %s is a marker gene for the cluster %s and is expressed in the spot %s", marker_gene, cluster_id, one_spot)}
    else {sprintf("The gene %s is a marker gene for the cluster %s, but not expressed in the spot %s", marker_gene, cluster_id, one_spot)}
}}
```

When I call check_spot(), it does not show errors and does not show the output as well.  Could please anyone help so I can get the similar result (but ore general, more number of markers) as shown by the first function? Even if I take the sample for marker only 5, it still does not work. Thank you very much.

Comment: You need a language tag

Comment: Edit it already.

Comment: Your function does not have a return value. Usually in R the last line of code whitin the scope of a `function` is considered as the return value. But a good practice is to use `return()`. That being said, consider including a sample of your data set to help you finding any issue

Comment: @ChrissPaul I think I have made a return value for the function with sprintf() right since sprintf is the last line to execute?

Comment: A function should include all the inputs in arguments however in your function, you are not declaring arguments properly in fact all the input arguments will be overwritten by subsequent code. Declare input correctly --

Answer (score 0):

Declare input arguments correctly

```
#Input should be something like this
check_spot = function(glio_spatial,glioblastoma){
```

Comment: I am confused with what you mean. My function argument is function(one_spot, cluster_id, marker_gene) and I defined those arguments in the function body as random. Therefore, when I call my function, I just need to use check_spot(), and before running the function, I have run all the dataset needed. Could you please explain in more details?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue by:

```
for (i in 1:length(marker_gene)){
    if (marker_gene[i] %in% intersection[1,]) return(sprintf("The gene %s is a marker gene for the cluster %s and is expressed in the spot %s", marker_gene, cluster_id, one_spot))
    else return(sprintf("The gene %s is a marker gene for the cluster %s, but not expressed in the spot %s", marker_gene, cluster_id, one_spot))
}
```